# Difference of a regular language and a context-free language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

I know that given the context-free language L and the regular language R, the language L \ R is context free. But what about R \ L ? My attempt is as follows:
 R \ L = R $\cap$ $\overline{L}$
We cannot know whether $\overline{L}$  is CF or not, so my guess is that we decide whether R \ L is context-free or not.
Am I right? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, there is one regular language $R$ of all possible words. So $R\setminus L=\overline{L}$. So if you know of CF languages $L$ so that $\overline{L}$ is not CF, then you are done.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, I am not given a particular L, so I cannot say anyhting about $\overline{L}$ . Am I correct in understanding your comment?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

> Since, regular languages are closed under complement property and context-free languages are not closed under complement property.